# Split vector into all combinations of given lengths and calculate summary stats

Tags: r, combinations

I have a vector of 5 values:

```
data <- c(42.3, 51.5, 53.7, 53.1, 50.7)
```

I want to split these values into one vector of length 2 and one vector of length three. Furthermore, I want to create every possible combination of such length 3 and length 2 vectors (in this case, 10 ways).

Here is a example of one such combination, with each value in "data" being represented once per column:

[image]

So far, I have this code to create all combinations of length 3:

```
table1 <- combn(data, 3)
```

This gives me the first table, with this output:

```
> table1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] 42.3 42.3 42.3 42.3 42.3 42.3 51.5 51.5 51.5  53.7
[2,] 51.5 51.5 51.5 53.7 53.7 53.1 53.7 53.7 53.1  53.1
[3,] 53.7 53.1 50.7 53.1 50.7 50.7 53.1 50.7 50.7  50.7
```

My plan is to create a second table by determine the difference between the original vector ("data") and each column in "table1", to obtain the corresponding length 2 vectors. However, I cannot figure out how to do so.

After I finish that, I plan to calculate a summary of the data (mean, sd, etc) by column, and comparing the two.

The problem is that `summary(table1)` works, but `sd(table1)` doesn't. I want my output to look like this:

```
> summary(table1)
       V1              V2              V3              V4             V5             V6             V7              V8       
 Min.   :42.30   Min.   :42.30   Min.   :42.30   Min.   :42.3   Min.   :42.3   Min.   :42.3   Min.   :51.50   Min.   :50.70  
 1st Qu.:46.90   1st Qu.:46.90   1st Qu.:46.50   1st Qu.:47.7   1st Qu.:46.5   1st Qu.:46.5   1st Qu.:52.30   1st Qu.:51.10  
 Median :51.50   Median :51.50   Median :50.70   Median :53.1   Median :50.7   Median :50.7   Median :53.10   Median :51.50  
 Mean   :49.17   Mean   :48.97   Mean   :48.17   Mean   :49.7   Mean   :48.9   Mean   :48.7   Mean   :52.77   Mean   :51.97  
 3rd Qu.:52.60   3rd Qu.:52.30   3rd Qu.:51.10   3rd Qu.:53.4   3rd Qu.:52.2   3rd Qu.:51.9   3rd Qu.:53.40   3rd Qu.:52.60  
 Max.   :53.70   Max.   :53.10   Max.   :51.50   Max.   :53.7   Max.   :53.7   Max.   :53.1   Max.   :53.70   Max.   :53.70  
       V9             V10      
 Min.   :50.70   Min.   :50.7  
 1st Qu.:51.10   1st Qu.:51.9  
 Median :51.50   Median :53.1  
 Mean   :51.77   Mean   :52.5  
 3rd Qu.:52.30   3rd Qu.:53.4  
 Max.   :53.10   Max.   :53.7
```

not like this

```
> sd(table1)
[1] 4.193394
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `finding the missing values (by comparing it to data) and then filling up the table like so`?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the first half with the code:

```html
mnumber <- function(input){
  return(setdiff(data, input))
}

table2 <- apply(table1, 2, mnumber)
```

This gives me the output

```html
> table2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] 53.1 53.7 53.7 51.5 51.5 51.5 42.3 42.3 42.3  42.3
[2,] 50.7 50.7 53.1 50.7 53.1 53.7 50.7 53.1 53.7  51.5
```

Now I just need to analyze the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `combn` on the indices of your vector and apply a function to each combination:

```
i <- seq_along(data)
l <- combn(i, 3, FUN = function(cmb){
  lapply(list(data[cmb], data[setdiff(i, cmb)]), function(v){
    c(summary(v), sd = sd(v))}
  )
}
, simplify = FALSE)
l[1]
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [[1]][[1]]
>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.        sd 
> 42.300000 46.900000 51.500000 49.166667 52.600000 53.700000  6.047589 
>
> [[1]][[2]]
>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.        sd 
> 50.700000 51.300000 51.900000 51.900000 52.500000 53.100000  1.697056
> ```